# Odoo structure not shown on windows

Tags: odoo

I have installed Odoo 9 on a windows 10 environment and after everything setup I cannot see Odoo icons, menus, etc.
I can only see a blank window with Odoo logo.
I have tested and the same happens with Odoo 11.

After some tests I found that adding "?debug" to web address it works fine.

1. Image 1: With standard web address (localhost:8069)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUPYR.png)
2. Image 2: Adding "?debug" to address
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY0O1.png)

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a browser cache problem.  Try disabling cache:

[image: Show picture]

Or, delete the file session (`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A\Odoo\Sessions\`).